# Часто ли Вы используете абстрактные классы в PHP?

Tags: php

И в каких случаях?
Есть такой пример, причем абстрактный класс вообще не понятно зачем тут использован:

```
<?php
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    // Наш абстрактный метод должен определять только необходимые аргументы
    abstract protected function prefixName($name);

}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass
{

    // Наш дочерний класс может также определять необязательные аргументы, не указанные в сигнатуре родительского метода
    public function prefixName($name, $separator = ".") {
        if ($name == "Pacman") {
            $prefix = "Mr";
        } elseif ($name == "Pacwoman") {
            $prefix = "Mrs";
        } else {
            $prefix = "";
        }
        return "{$prefix}{$separator} {$name}";
    }
}

$class = new ConcreteClass;
echo $class->prefixName("Pacman"), "\n";
echo $class->prefixName("Pacwoman"), "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Крайне редко. Когда нужен конракт, нужно применять интерфейсы, иначе конечный пользователь обязан наследоваться от конкретного класса, а, возможно, у него уже есть готовая имплементация на руках с совсем другой иерархией. Абстрактный класс, в отличие от интерфейса, действует противоположным путем, интерфейс заставляет расширять функционал класса, а абсрактный класс наоборот, его ограничивает и впридачу привешивает какие-то свои методы. Я его использую только в двух случаях - когда он будет выполнять только роль промежуточного звена в иерархии (например, abstract HttpRequestException наследуется ServerErrorException и BadRequestException, и сам HttpRequestException не должен быть нигде вызван напрямую, н может вобрать в себя общий функционал ServerErrorException и BadRequestException) и когда нужно сделать базовую реализацию итерфейса (того функционала, который, скорее всего, потребуется всем имплементациям интерфейса).

Comment: Тогда разверну свой ответ. Стоит задача написания пагинации страниц с учетов выбранного фильтра(поиска) для 4-х сущностей. Какую структуру удобно было бы применить?

Comment: Можно от Вас получить пример реального нужного применения интерфейcа?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk любое место, где реализация отвязана: либо много однотипных решений (MemoryStream, FileStream, etc), либо конкретное решение и вовсе неизвестно (PluginInterface). У меня, например, в текущем проекте так организован middleware: есть RequestFilterInterface, который принимается на вход фильтром-обработчиком и позволяет выцепить utm-метку / вставить уникальный хэш пользователю на каждом запросе. При этом в контроллер, понятное дело, лазать совсем необязательно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут, человек в комментарии все четко написал, с примерами [http://www.askdev.ru/](http://www.askdev.ru/php/6981/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-PHP-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8B/)

Comment: Особенно четко это сформулировал второй человек (@aboutmagic) :


    Так что в PHP абстрактные методы и интерфейсы это декларативные инструменты управления исходным кодом, в отличие от языков со статической типизацией.